# ROS tutorial slides

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you recommend some ROS tutorial slides available out there on the internet?
I have to give a crash course, and I would rather borrow the support of somebody more expert than me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246600/ros-tutorial-slides/) by [antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23427/antonio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are extensive slides on the ROS framework from a 2013 summer course at ISR.
http://mediawiki.isr.ist.utl.pt/wiki/Summer_course_on_ROS_framework_2013

---

Originally posted by [antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/23427/antonio/) with karma: 93 on 2016-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0